# Increase margins for grid.arrange view

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2, r-grid

I have the following code which plots 8 ggplots on one page, 3 on the first and second columns and 2 on the third. Is it possible to increase the outer margins as the plots are very close to the edges of the pdf?

```
pdf("J:/GROUPS/Team/201708.pdf",width=26,height=18,pointsize=10)
grid.arrange(UK1, UK2, UK3, UK4, UK5, UK6, UK7, UK8)

dev.off()
```

Comment: After further exploration I have realised I would need to use the theme function within each ggplot to alter the margins.